# I can no longer hear people over voice chat

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

I have been able to hear voice chat fine previously, but recently everyone has been effectively muted( I think this is following a sound driver error). I have checked my settings and voice chat is turned up to 100

Not a single thing has changed aside from updates, Why can't I hear anyone anymore?

Comment: I've had this issue, can you check to make sure your device is not in surround sound? That was my issue.

Comment: This was actually fixed for me during Operation Health 2.1.2 when they updated the voice codec

Comment: Ah, that's good. I personally still have that issue a lot though so I figure'd I'd at least comment it XD

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue forever and there are posts all over the place that talk about it, but not every solution works for everyone. The main solution I've seen suggested is updating drivers, however that didn't work for me.

My issue was that UPlay actually set my headset/whatever output the sound intended to go to my ears to my second monitor, instead. Effectively, it was trying to output sound through a TV screen instead of my earbuds. Changing that back to my computer fixed it right up! It's in the audio settings in UPlay when you open it up, not in the game.

Answer (score 1):

I recently moved to a dorm with the local internet. When I started using my mobile internet for R6, the voice chat started working. So for me, it was because of the internet provider, I suppose. Hope it helps.